# How to use the rubymine debugger for rails using vagrant

Tags: ruby-on-rails, intellij-idea, vagrant, rubymine

I researched but i cannot find how to do it.

I want to be able to use the rails server and all my environment of my rails app in vagrant and debug that in my ruby mine.

Answer (score 0):

All the information you need is on jetbrains page take a [look](https://www.jetbrains.com/ruby/help/configuring-remote-interpreters-via-virtual-boxes.html)